# Features doesn't create field instances

Tags: 7, features

I have recreated a feature with all field instances checked. but when I enable it in new site, only entities and content types are created not their fields.

In the feature's .info file there is lot of lines like this:

```
features_exclude[field][profile2-personel_information-field_myfield] = profile2-personel_information-field_myfield
```

I also removed these lines, but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: When you say recreated - were these fields in a different feature beforehand?

Comment: @Chapabu Yes. The fields were created by a feature